# CSA - Pulses on the output of the low side current measurement amplifier

Tags: current, motor-controller, shunt

I'm a bit lost at the moment, since I see pulses on the output of my CSA and I cannot really see, why this happens.

The pulses occur immediately, when I apply a PWM signal to the gate driver (DRV8300DI), but not every PWM cycle, the puls is large, sometimes it has only small pulses:

**Pulses occur already, without any motor attached**:

[image]

I'm doing low side current measurement, that is the main reason why I don't understand the occurence of the pulses. I read, that it might have to do with the low shunt resistor of only 300uOhm, since the damping is less for the same inductance, but the INA240 should work without any problem without input filter (it is not recommended to use a input filter).

**Schematic**:

[image]
[image]

**Layout**:

Overview:
[image]
Overview:
[image]
TOP Layer:
[image]
GND Layer:
[image]
PWR Layer:
[image]
BOT Layer:
[image]

**What I have done**:

- Changed the CSA (from INA286 to INA240, which has way more Bandwidth and PWM suppression)
- There is no significant noise on the 3V3 line, which I measured with a spring probe
- When I change the gate resistors from 10Ohm to 39Ohm, the pulses become longer and are higher in amplitude, that was really surprising for me
- I desoldered already R9 (low side gate resistor) and the pulses are gone, so it seems the MOSFET directly couple into the amplifier when switching
- I also removed R11, since I first tought, the gate is coupling over the resistor

**Rise and Fall time with 10Ohm gate resistor (16ns)**:

[image]
[image]

**When I attach a motor (it runs immediately in overcurrent)**:

[image]
[image]

**Datasheets**:

INA240: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina240.pdf?ts=1653767662344&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FINA240
DRV8300DI: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8300.pdf?ts=1653788051038

Any ideas, what could cause this problems? The decoupling caps on the INA240 might not be ideal and also the GLA loop is also not optimal, but that should not give so much problems. I have already done In-Phase CSA with a INA240 and I never have seen such a pulsing behaviour.

**Edit:**

It might be possible, that I have a shot-through and that this is the cause of the current spikes. When I measure the GLx and GHx Signals, they look like this:

For 10Ohm gate resistors, rising and falling:
[image]
[image]

For 39Ohm gate resistors, rising and falling:
[image]
[image]

But since GHx is already on the SHx potential when the GLx is rising, I don't see the shot through here. With the 39Ohm gate resistor, the MOSFETs get a little bit warm without load, so it must be a shoot through. How should the signals look like, when there is no shot-through?

Comment: Drain-source capacitance of MOSFETs when switching will inject current pulses into the sense resistor when the MOSFETs are switching (no motor fitted). Are you aware of that?

Comment: DCR of motor should tell you why it is current limiting, but parasitics will affect transient response.

Comment: Hi Andy, do you mean the pulses should get lower, when there is a motor?

Comment: Hi Tony, the controller seems to reach overcurrent and I think i measures one of the pulses

Comment: I know now that it is not shot through that lead to the pulses, the problem with the 39 ohm resistors is, that the Cgd couples into the gate when the high side switches on and the resistor is too low to counteract this. Still I am unable to find out, why I can see this kind of pulses. As you metioned andy, it is probably what you told in your comment, but also when I add a 100 ohm resistor to gnd at the output, i see no difference. I think the CSA are sensitive to small pulses and give out a step response